# Unable to send emails using nodemailer and Gmail in Node.js

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, nodemailer, pdfkit, express-handlebars

I'm trying to implement email sending functionality in my Node.js application using nodemailer and Gmail as the email service provider. However, I'm encountering an issue where the emails are not being sent successfully. I've gone through the following steps to set up the email sending functionality:

Installed the required packages: I have installed the nodemailer package (npm install nodemailer) and handlebars package (npm install handlebars) in my project.

Verified Gmail account credentials: I have confirmed that the Gmail account credentials (email address and password) provided in the auth section of the nodemailer transporter are correct.

Enabled access for less secure apps: I have enabled the "Allow less secure apps" option in my Gmail account settings to allow nodemailer to access the account.

Despite these steps, I am still unable to send emails. When testing the functionality, the server returns a 500 Internal Server Error.

Here is an overview of my code:

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const PDFDocument = require("pdfkit");
const handlebars = require("handlebars");
const {
  allowInsecurePrototypeAccess,
} = require("@handlebars/allow-prototype-access");
const hbs = require("nodemailer-express-handlebars");

// Create Express app
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Serve the HTML form
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Connected");
});

// Handle form submission
app.post("/warranty-register", async (req, res) => {
  const formData = req.body;

  try {
    // Generate PDF
    const pdfBuffer = await generatePDF(
      formData
    );

    // Send email with PDF attachment
    await sendEmail(email, firstName, pdfBuffer);

    res.send(
      "Registration successful! An email has been sent to you with the form information."
    );
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send("Failed to register. Please try again later.");
  }
});

// Generate PDF document
function generatePDF(
  formData
) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const doc = new PDFDocument();
    const pdfChunks = [];

    // Build PDF content
    doc
     ........building PDF
    }

    // Push PDF content chunks
    doc.on("data", (chunk) => pdfChunks.push(chunk));
    doc.on("end", () => resolve(Buffer.concat(pdfChunks)));

    // Finalize PDF document
    doc.end();
  });
}

// Send email with PDF attachment
async function sendEmail(email, firstName, pdfBuffer) {
  try {
    // Create a nodemailer transporter
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: "Gmail",
      auth: {
      user: "xxx@xxx.com",
      pass: `${password}`,
      },
    });

    const handlebarsOptions = {
      viewEngine: {
        extname: ".hbs",
        partialsDir: path.resolve(__dirname, "views"),
        defaultLayout: false,
        handlebars: allowInsecurePrototypeAccess(handlebars),
      },
      viewPath: path.resolve(__dirname, "views"),
      extName: ".hbs",
    };

    transporter.use("compile", hbs(handlebarsOptions));

    // Compose email options
    const mailOptions = {
      from: "xxx@xxx.com",
      to: email,
      subject: "Form Information",
      template: "email",
      context: {
        firstName: firstName,
      },
      attachments: [
        {
          filename: "form_information.pdf",
          content: pdfBuffer,
        },
        {
          filename: "company_logo.png",
          path: path.resolve(__dirname, "asset/img", "logo.png"),
          cid: "logo",
        },
      ],
    };

    // Send email
    return await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error, "Failed to send email. Please try again later.");
  }
}

// Start the server
app.listen(8500, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port 8500`);
});
```

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const PDFDocument = require("pdfkit");
const handlebars = require("handlebars");
const {
  allowInsecurePrototypeAccess,
} = require("@handlebars/allow-prototype-access");
const hbs = require("nodemailer-express-handlebars");

// Create Express app
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Serve the HTML form
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Connected");
});

// Handle form submission
app.post("/warranty-register", async (req, res) => {
  const formData = req.body;

  try {
    // Generate PDF
    const pdfBuffer = await generatePDF(
      formData
    );

    // Send email with PDF attachment
    await sendEmail(email, firstName, pdfBuffer);

    res.send(
      "Registration successful! An email has been sent to you with the form information."
    );
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send("Failed to register. Please try again later.");
  }
});

// Generate PDF document
function generatePDF(
  formData
) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const doc = new PDFDocument();
    const pdfChunks = [];

    // Build PDF content
    doc
     ........building PDF
    }

    // Push PDF content chunks
    doc.on("data", (chunk) => pdfChunks.push(chunk));
    doc.on("end", () => resolve(Buffer.concat(pdfChunks)));

    // Finalize PDF document
    doc.end();
  });
}

// Send email with PDF attachment
async function sendEmail(email, firstName, pdfBuffer) {
  try {
    // Create a nodemailer transporter
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: "Gmail",
      auth: {
      user: "xxx@xxx.com",
      pass: `${password}`,
      },
    });


    const templatePath = path.join(__dirname, "./email.html");
    const templateContent = fs.readFileSync(templatePath, "utf8");

    // Compose email options
    const mailOptions = {
      from: "xxx@xxx.com",
      to: email,
      subject: "Form Information",
      html: templateContent,
      attachments: [
        {
          filename: "form_information.pdf",
          content: pdfBuffer,
        },
      ],
    };

    // Send email
    return await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error, "Failed to send email. Please try again later.");
  }
}

// Start the server
app.listen(8500, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port 8500`);
});
```

With the above code, I can successfully send an email with the HTML content from the email.html file and the attachment of formData.

I have also tried enabling verbose logging for nodemailer by setting the debug option to true when creating the transporter, but it doesn't provide any additional helpful information.

Can anyone help me identify the cause of this issue? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!